# How to pass data from vuex store through module to vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

> I'm able to console data, as well as able to see data in vuex dev tool
>   but not able to display them in table. Please if someone could check
>   my code and tell me what is wrong with it. Thanks folks. I tried differents methods like async/await, promise, getters... but I was not able to to get the data, probably I was not calling it properly.

**ROLE.VUE**

```
<emplate>
  <di>
    <p v-for="(role, index) in roles :key="index">
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default ({
  name: 'Role',
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'Role'
  },

  created  () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles').then((response) => { console.log(response) })
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'roles'
    ])
  }
})

</script>
```

**role.js**

```
import Axios from 'axios'

export default {
//   namespaced: true,

  state: {
    roles: [],
  },

  getters: {
    roles (state) {
      return state.roles
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_ROLES (state, roles) {
      state.roles = roles
    }
  },

  actions: {

loadRoles ({ commit }) {
  Axios.get('/settings/roles')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      //   let roles = response.data
      commit('SET_ROLES', response.data.roles)
    })
}
```

}
}

**index.js**

```
import role from './role'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {

  },

  mutations: {
    //
  },

  modules: {
    role
  },

  actions: {
    //
  }
})
```

**Main.js**

```
import { store } from './store/store'
new Vue({
router,
store,
ValidationProvider,
render: h => h(App)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading from a module with `mapState`, you need to specify the name of the module you are loading from.  Here is the proper syntax for your case:

```
...mapState('role', ['roles'])
```

The first argument is the module name, and the second is an array of `state` properties from that module.

Comment: I'm getting this error. [vuex] unknown action type: loadRoles vuex.esm.js:419.  Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.$store.dispatch(...) is undefined"

Comment: That will be unrelated to any mapping, it's an error from where you've tried to access the store through the Vue instance property.  The reason for that error is also syntax.  It should be `this.$store.dispatch('role/loadRoles')`.  It may be handy for you to consult documentation to learn syntax of using vuex modules.

Comment: The error message is gone but data still not showing in vue component

Comment: You're not doing anything to show it.  This is also wrong syntax:  `<p v-for="(role, index) in roles :key="index">`.  You didn't close the quotes of the `v-for`, and even then, it only creates `p` elements and sets a key but doesn't actually attempt to show any data.  You'd need something like `<p v-for="(role, index) in roles" :key="index">{{ role }}</p>`.  If you're brand new to Vue, I would try out some tutorials first.

Comment: Actually I used I found that error earlier and fixed, even though the console below is loggin undefined. created  () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadRoles').then((response) => { console.log(response) })
  },

Comment: It's undefined because you didn't return anything from the method to chain `.then` from. It should work if you return the Axios promise like: `return Axios.get('/settings/roles')`.   Please upvote/accept my answer if it solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: ,you are completely right. I comment this line while I was troubleshooting the codes. <pre>let roles = response.data, commit('SET_ROLES', roles)<code>. It is now working as expected. Thanks a lot